# Build a Jenkins pipeline (job) from another repo on another branch

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

What I am trying to do doesn't seem so complex but not so easy, but what I've read by now seems to make it look like I am launching rockets.

Basically let's say I have

```
my-deploys-repo with branches: master, develop
my-tools-repo with whatever branches
```

```
Inside my-tools-repo I have: Jenkinsfile-push-events ( jenkins pipeline )
Inside my-deploys-repo I have ON DEVELOP BRANCH: Jenkinsfile-deploy (which also gets some params, if it matters )
```

How can I trigger Jenkinsfile-deploy job from my-deploys-repo's develop branch FROM Jenkinsfile-push-events on my-tools-repo?

I understood that normally I'd do something like (inside Jenkinsfile-push-events)

```
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    build job: '../my-deploys-repo/Jenkinsfile-deploy'   
                }
            }
```

But it laying on another branch seems like a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Job in Jenkins has its definition in its properties and that already includes Jenkinsfile, so you cannot trigger a "Jenkinsfile" without defining a Job that uses that Jenkinsfile first.

If you have two branches, you need a Multibranch Pipeline job.

Let's say you created a new Multibranch Pipeline job — say `MyJob` is its name —  that is configured to use your repo (`my-deploys-repo.git`) and your path to Jenkinsfile (`Jenkinsfile-deploy.groovy`). You can then trigger that job by:

```
build job: "MyJob/develop", wait: false, propagate: false,
    parameters: [
         string(name: 'PARAM_1', value: "1"),
         string(name: 'PARAM_2', value: "maybe"), //etc.
   ]
```

Comment: Worked, but the current problem is that the build for some reason goes to pending, but If I trigger it manually it starts just fine. Hmmm this is weird. I'd be very curious to know why

Comment: Maybe you defined max 1 build concurrently?